# Split string into multiple rows by capital letters with cSplit

Tags: r, strsplit, csplit

I have survey data. Some questions allowed for multiple answers. In my data, the different answers are separated by a comma. I want to add a new row in the dataframe for each choice. So I have something like this:

```
survey$q1 <- c("I like this", "I like that", "I like this, but not much",
 "I like that, but not much", "I like this,I like that", 
"I like this, but not much,I like that")
```

If commas were only there to divide the multiple choices I'd use:

```
survey <- cSplit(survey, "q1", ",", direction = "long")
```

and get the desired result.
Given some commas are part of the answer, I tried using comma followed by capital letter as a divider:

```
survey <- cSplit(survey, "q1", ",(?=[A-Z])", direction = "long")
```

But for some reason it does not work. It does not give any error, but it does not split strings and also it removes some rows from the dataframe.
I then tried using strsplit:

```
strsplit(survey$1, ",(?=[A-Z])", perl=T)
```

which works in splitting it correctly, but I'm not able to implement it so that each sentence becomes a different row of the same column, like cSplit does.
The required output is:

```
survey$q1
[1] "I like this"
[2] "I like that"
[3] "I like this, but not much"
[4] "I like that, but not much"
[5] "I like this"
[6] "I like that"
[7] "I like this, but not much"
[8] "I like that"
```

Is there a way I can get it using one of the 2 methods? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
survey %>% 
   separate_rows(q1, sep=",(?=[A-Z])")
#                       q1
#1               I like this
#2               I like that
#3 I like this, but not much
#4 I like that, but not much
#5               I like this
#6               I like that
#7 I like this, but not much
#8               I like that
```

---

With `cSplit`, there is an argument `fixed` which is `TRUE` by default, but if we use `fixed = FALSE`, it may fail.  May be because it is not optimized for PCRE regex expressions

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(survey, "q1", ",(?=[A-Z])", direction = "long", fixed = FALSE)
```

> Error in strsplit(indt[[splitCols[x]]], split = sep[x], fixed = fixed)
>   :    invalid regular expression ',(?=[A-Z])', reason 'Invalid regexp'

One option to bypass it would be to modify the column with a function (`sub/gsub`) that can take PCRE regex to change the `sep` and then use `cSplit` on that `sep`

```
cSplit(transform(survey, q1 = sub(",(?=[A-Z])", ":", q1, perl = TRUE)), 
         "q1", sep=":", direction = "long")
#                        q1
#1:               I like this
#2:               I like that
#3: I like this, but not much
#4: I like that, but not much
#5:               I like this
#6:               I like that
#7: I like this, but not much
#8:               I like that
```

#### data

```
survey <- structure(list(q1 = c("I like this", "I like that", "I like this, but not much", 
"I like that, but not much", "I like this,I like that", "I like this, but not much,I like that"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: thank you. I tried but I got this error, I don't know why it wouldn't work with characters:

Error in UseMethod("separate_rows_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_rows_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @Antonio Can you try on the `data` I showed on my post

Comment: I did, I actually get the same error. Plus I have to use survey$q1 as x, rather than just q1

Comment: I tried checking the cSplit part, you are right, that's exactly what happens

Comment: @Antonio. `separate_rows` takes the data.frame and column name as 'q1'.  But if you are using `survey$q1`, I don't see the point why you use `cSplit`

Comment: @Antonio I updateddd with `cSplit`, should work now

Comment: @Antonio Regarding your comment `Plus I have to use survey$q1 as x, rather than just q1`, It is. not the case when you used `cSplit`

Comment: Thank you! it works almost perfectly, there is still a couple of answers it does not detect but I'll play around with it until it does!

Comment: regarding the Plus I have to use survey$q1 as x, rather than just q1, I meant that I got an error using your initial solution with separate_rows

Comment: @Antonio. Okay., then I don't find why you are using `cSplit` instead of `strsplit`

Comment: @Antonio `separate_rows` is from `tidyr`.  I use the dev version of `tidyr`, though it should work if your version is CRAN up-to-date recent version

Comment: because I have other columns with ID for example and I need the ID variable to have the same value for the 2 parts of the string that are now 2 different rows

Comment: Oh ok I'll check the version. Thank you very much

Comment: actually there was nothing to add to your code, I had strings that needed to be split into 3 parts and just running the same command twice did the trick. I don't understand why, but that's fine

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @akrun is the right one.
I just wanted to add that, if you need some strings to be split into more than 2 parts, the way for his code to work is simply to run the same line multiple times.
I'm not entirely sure why this is the case, but it works